# Odd issue with escaped records and adding to an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have some PHP code I use to pull records from a database, put them into an array, put that array into another array, and then format that array into JSON.  Connecting to the database and pulling the information works great, as does building the second array and conversion into JSON.  But certain records (12 out of 175) are apparently coming up blank when put into the first array.  I'm sure it has something to do with non-escaped and non-standard characters, but I can't for the life of me figure out what I need to do to make sure it gets added to the array correctly. I've tried adding `addslashes` and `htmlentities` to make sure it wasn't a standard escape issue, but it's still happening.  All the the records are currently encoded as ASCII.

Here are the results that are coming up blank when added to the array:

```
A Gentlewoman’s Lament
By true record of the Doctor Bede
A Lover’s Lament
Complaint þat Crist maketh of his Passioun
How þe louer is sett to serve þe floure
Fifteen O’s of Christ
Balade made by Lydgate at þe Departyng of Thomas Chaucyer on Ambassade into France
On the Mutability of Man’s Nature due to the Seasons, the Elements, the Complexions, and the Planets
That now is hay þat sumtyme was grasse
Balade on a New Year’s Gift of an Eagle presented to King Henry VI in 1428
Everything draweþe to his semblable
Pélerinage de la vie humaine
```

And here's the code that I use to pull that information from the SQL results:

```
while ($row = $work_result->fetch_array())
{
    echo $row['Work'] . "<BR/>";
    $encoding = mb_detect_encoding(htmlentities($row['Work']));
    $work_array = array('id'=>$row['id'],'name'=>addslashes(htmlentities($row['Work'])),'encoding'=>$encoding, 'type'=>'work','color'=>'midnightblue');
    var_dump($work_array);
    echo "<BR/>";
    array_push($array, $work_array);
}
```

I'm at a total loss.  I'm sure there's a function I'm just not using, but what it is I have no idea.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where's the actual JSON converting code? It may be that you are using non-utf8 string with `json_encode` which only supports utf8.

Comment: The strings are ASCII, though, and my understanding is that utf8 is a superset of ASCII.  Still my code to convert to JSON is:

'json_encode($items_array);'

'$items_array' is the larger array these arrays are a part of.

Comment: Just to check I added a specific utf8_encode statement in my code, so that it states 

 $test_array = array('id'=>$row['id'],'name'=>utf8_encode(addslashes(htmlentities($row['Work']))),'encoding'=>$encoding, 'type'=>'work','color'=>'midnightblue');


this has no effect.

Comment: Try getting rid of `htmlentities()` and leave `addslashes()` only.

Comment: create your array `$array` via this way `$array = array();` first, then run it again.

Comment: I do generate the `$array` that way earlier in the code -- sorry I didn't mention it earlier.  Removing `htmlentities()` resulted in no results whatsoever.

Comment: @medievalmatt Do the blank records occur before of after `json_encode`? If after, read the first comment. If before, then you misled me by mentioning JSON in the question.

Comment: Before, but as I said in my initial description the conversion into JSON is fine.  The issue is with pushing the strings returned from the database to the first array.  I apologize if you feel I misled you, but I have been chastised for not giving what I considered extraneous information in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode your string.

```
$work_array = array('name'=>urlencode($row['Work']));
```

Comment: It's really weird = `addslashes` results in null results, and while `urlencode` works it then breaks when the resulting json is applied by d3-vased visualization. 

I've determined that the characters that are breaking things are ',þ, and é.  So it's definitely escapes and non-standard characters.